# Tried creating sql tables but shows error

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

The Query I used for creating table
    create table add(

```
 -> id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        -> firstname char(50),
        -> lastname char(50),
        -> email varchar(50),
        -> password varchar(50),
        -> confirmPassword varchar(50),
        -> mobileNo varchar(20),
        -> location varchar(50),
        -> PRIMARY KEY(id)
        -> );
```

Comment: What are those arrows?

Comment: @GurV they seem to be mysql's prompt for a multi-line command.

Comment: multi line command

Comment: **problem is solved** thanks anyways @paul :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` is a reserved word. Changing the table's name would probably be the best approach, but if this isn't possible, you can escape it by using backticks:

```
create table `add`( -- Here!
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname char(50),
    lastname char(50),
    email varchar(50),
    password varchar(50),
    confirmPassword varchar(50),
    mobileNo varchar(20),
    location varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: Done, it helped,! :)